# Order by joined field with many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

In PostgreSQL database there are two entities with many-to-many relation: `songs` have many to many `artists`. `artists_songs` table is used for the relation. I want to select songs and sort them by the first artist (sorted alphabetically). Currently PG doesn't allow me doing that without specifying all fields in group by. Is it possible to do the select and sort songs with grouping only by `songs.id`?

Here is my SQL query:

```
select ss.*
  from (
    select songs.*, min(artists.name) as artist_name
    from songs
      left join artists_songs on artists_songs.song_id = songs.id
      left join artists on artists.id = artists_songs.artist_id
      group by songs.id, artists.name
    ) ss
    group by ss.id
    order by ss.artist_name
    ;
```

Comment: Don't GROUP BY columns that are arguments to set functions, e.g. artists.name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a good spot for a lateral join:

```
select s.*, a.name
from songs s
cross join lateral (
    select a.name
    from artists_songs ars
    inner join artists a on a.id = ars.artist_id
    where ars.song_id = s.id
    order by a.name
    limit 1
) a
order by a.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (s.id) s.*, sa.name as artist_name
from songs s left join
     artists_songs ars
     on ars.song_id = s.id left join
     artists a
     on a.id = ars.artist_id    
order by s.id, sa.name;
```

If you want particular ordering, you can use a subquery:

```
select s.*
from (select distinct on (s.id) s.*, sa.name as artist_name
      from songs s left join
           artists_songs ars
           on ars.song_id = s.id left join
           artists a
           on a.id = ars.artist_id    
      order by s.id, sa.name
     ) s
order by artist_name
```

Comment: I think the window function is preferable answer here. So the first version was good enough. I've not mentioned, but the query will have more joins and looks way more complicated. Thanks anyway, your answer is accepted!

Comment: Also the leading `order by s.id` will break ordering, artist name has more weight.

Comment: @ka8725 . . . Why do you think a window function would be better?  In Postgres, `distinct on` usually has the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've come up so far is using window function as @gordon-linoff stated initially:

```
select s.id, min(a.name) over (partition by s.id) as artist_name
from songs s left join
    artists_songs ars
    on ars.song_id = s.id left join
    artists a
    on a.id = ars.artist_id
order by artist_name;
```

Comment: When a song has several artists, this solution will duplicate the rows. I am not sure this is what you want.